# Surprising numerical coincidence while interpolating on Smolyak grid

Tags: polynomials, interpolation

I was plotting 2-D shape functions for linear interpolation on a Smolyak sparse grid of level 2 associated to Gauss-Lobatto-Chebyshev nodes(cf https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_grid ), when I came across a surprising coincidence: the polynomial Smolyak interpolation is extremely close to the RBF interpolation (**without** added global polynomial). For instance, the Smolyak shape function associated to the bottom left node looks something like this, and the corresponding RBF shape function is visually indistinguishable.

[image]

Numerically, the two field have a maximum difference of ~0.5%.
Let me stress that this is particularly surprizing (at least to me) because on the one hand, you have a polynomial, and on the other hand a sum of gaussians. Such a similarity does not arize for other RBFs (thin plate, linear, multiquadrique, ...) or other scattered data interpolation method.

For reference, the grid looks something like this.[image: Smolyak sparse grid]

My question is: does someone have some kind of an explanation for this phenomenon?

Answer (score 2):

This is no coincidence! The link between RBF and multivariate interpolation has been explored in the literature. In [1] for instance, the author shows that the limit of the RBF interpolation process as the basis functions are scaled to become wider and wier, is (under additional assumptions) a multivariate polynomial.

[1] Schaback, R. (2005). Multivariate interpolation by polynomials and radial basis functions. Constructive Approximation, 21(3), 293-317.